# Unicode issue with freetype (C)

Tags: c, linux, unicode, freetype, neko

I currently working on a library for the [NekoVM](http://nekovm.org/) to create a binding to [Freetype](http://www.freetype.org/) 2. It is written in plain c and it all works really nice, except when the user enters some unicode chars like "ü", "Ä" or "ß" they will be transformed into to some ugly square-like letters.
When I recieve the data from the NekoVM you use [`val_string`](http://nekovm.org/doc/ffi#access_functions) which returns a `char*`. The function ([`FT_Load_Char`](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Load_Char)) where you push the data into freetype expects a unsigned long as char code. (Every letter is processed on its own.)

What to do get the characters rendered correctly? I also have the option to convert them into any ISO-8859-XX code page before submitting them into the c written library.

Comment: Does each of the non-ASCII characters turn into a single box? Or do they turn into more than one character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was quite simple:

```
for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
    unsigned long c = FT_Get_Char_Index(face,r[i]);
    FT_Load_Glyph(face,uc,FT_LOAD_RENDER);
    ....
}
```

This makes freetype handle all the "encoding-stuff" at it own.

Answer (score 3):

A little square box means that your character isn't contained in the font. That can mean two things:

1. Use a font which contains these characters
2. Use the correct encoding. See [FT_CharMap](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_CharMap) and [FT_Encoding](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Encoding).

Comment: the char is in the font (it is the same I use on my OS and there these chars are displayed.)

Comment: In that case, it's an encoding issue.